# Types of singularities in ODE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, singular-solution

Consider the nonlinear ODE $$y\cdot\frac{d^{2}y}{dx^{2}}-\left(\frac{dy}{dx}\right)^{2}+1=0$$ with $y : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$.

As seen, it does not satisfy Picard–Lindelöf theorem because of singularity at $y=0$. Nevertheless it possesses smooth solutions, for example $y(x) = \frac{1}{a}\cos ax$ for $a \ne 0$. On the other hand, all the solutions of $$y\cdot\frac{d^{2}y}{dx^{2}} + \left(\frac{dy}{dx}\right)^{2}+1=0$$ explode when $y$ approaches $0$.

The first singularity leads to violation of uniqueness, while the second breaks the solutions.

Are there special terms for these types of singularities? A study? The term "regular singular point" seems to have a different meaning.

---

I expect a term for the singularity of the first equation like "*passable*" or "*permeable*", but I didn't find any of them in math literature.

Answer (score 0):

That might be a coordinate or removable singularity. With some change of variables, there seems to be a meaningful value at $y=0$. Either way I think its solidly a Type I singularity: [Mathematical Singularities](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singularity_(mathematics))

$y\frac{d^2y}{dx^2}-(\frac{dy}{dx})^2+1=0$

$\frac{d}{dx}(\frac{dy/dx}{y})=-1/y^2$

$=\frac{d^2}{dx^2}(\ln y)=-1/y^2$

$u=\ln {y}$

$\frac{d^2}{dx^2}u=-e^{-2u}$

$\frac{du}{dx}\frac{d^2}{dx^2}u=-e^{-2u}\frac{du}{dx}$

$(du/dx)^2=c_1+e^{-2u}$

$\frac{du}{\sqrt{c_1+e^{-2u}}}=dx=\frac{dy}{y \sqrt{c_1+1/y^2}}=\frac{dy}{\sqrt{c_1y^2+1}}$

$\sqrt{c_1}y=\tan\theta\implies dy=\sec^2{\theta}d\theta/\sqrt{c_1}$

$\frac{1}{\sqrt{c_1y^2+1}}=\cos{\theta}$

$\int dy/[...]=\int(1/\sqrt{c_1})\sec{\theta}d\theta=\frac{1}{\sqrt{c_1}}\ln|\frac{1+\sqrt{c_1}y}{\sqrt{1+c_1y^2}}|+c_2=x$

Plug $y=0$ into that, you get  $x=c_2$.

$\frac{1+\sqrt{c_1}y}{\sqrt{1+c_1y^2}}=c_3e^{\sqrt{c_1}x}$

$[(1+c_1y^2)c_3^2e^{2\sqrt{c_1}x}-1]^2=c_1y^2$

This will give you a fourth order polynomial in y with coefficients consisting of an exponential function of x.

Comment: If the first singularity is of coordinate type, then what a transformation removes it? The transformation $u=\ln y$ does not remove actually, but just moves it to infinity. The words "permeable" or "passable" fit better, but i didn't find them in math literature.